# Problem in publishing artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, dockerfile, playwright

**Background**

I have a Jenkins pipeline setup on an enterprise network.

To build the image, I have a Dockerfile that uses the official Playwright image and installs some dependencies. I push my image to ECR.

The pipeline has a stage where I use a DIND agent to run playwright tests. The tests run inside the Docker container, which I created above, using a bash script. In the bash script, I pull the image and run the container with a bind-mount volume from the Jenkins workspace directory(host) to the app(container). After that, I use the Docker exec command to run the playwright tests with "pwuser". The Jenkins pipeline runs with the "pipeline" user.

Till here, everything works fine.

**Problem**

After the tests, I want to publish the artifacts (test results) in Jenkins, but for some reason, I only see all the files except the test-results directory.

I am able to browse the folder on the EC2 agent where the pipeline runs, and all the files, including the test-results have the same user group of "pipeline".

I apologize that I can't provide the code, but any help will be highly appreciated. Feel free to comment with any queries.

Comment: Post tests, the test results directory is cleaned up? Without code, speculations are inevitable

Comment: No the directory remains. there is no cleanup. After ```ls -al``` inside container I am able to see the test results folder but I don't see the folder outside the container when doing ls in jenkins. But I am able to see the folder when I log in to EC2 as different user.

Comment: Okay. Jenkins uses UID `1000`  to have write access to workspace directory which is mounted from the host volumes. It could be that  the docker container user is writing to  directory which is not Jenkins workspace.